# Launch Manager for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, acer-aspire-one

Acer has an utility called Launch Manager for Windows 7 and below that displays an icon on the screen when you press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> or when you change the volume/brightness using the keyboard.

However I can't find the version for Windows 8. I have installed the windows 7 version but it didn't work. Is there an alternative for this application on windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we all know that Windows-8 final version is not release yet, so there could be not all official driver released yet for Windows-8.

You can run the driver/setup.exe in the compatibility mode by right click on it which is the recent feature of Windows-7 as well. May be then it work for Windows-8 but I'm not sure 100% about it.

Comment: The part about official driver is not true, since I am able to get all my drivers (LAN, wifi, sound, VGA...) on the Acer website already. But I will try the compatibility mode, thanks!

Comment: @Chin I'll edit that for you :)

Comment: I ran it on compatibility mode for windows 7 and it works perfectly now! Thanks a lot! You may want to update your answer as well.

Comment: oh I just realized that the icons won't display when I'm in a modern UI app, so the solution is not yet perfect. But I will have to bear with it for now and wait for the official release.

Answer (score 0):

Not according to acer's site. Though I'm sure that shortly after release there will be an updated version released that does support windows 8.

Keep checking the driver downloads page for your model, if one is released you will find it it there.